# add watermark in pdf when downloading PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5

following code work for  to download PDF from server and rename it when user download that pdf

```
       PurchasesIssuesYear pobj = new PurchasesIssuesYearServ().getFirstOrDefault(id);
            if (pobj != null)
            {                    
                string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/FileData/" + pobj.uploadActualforDownload;
                byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
                string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);
                var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = pobj.acadYear + .pdf",
                    Inline = false,
                };
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                return File(filedata, contentType);
             }
```

Now, When user download PDF needs to add email id as water mark of that user in every page of pdf

Comment: To apply a watermark, you need a PDF library featuring watermarks and process the PDF in question before download. Which PDF library will you use for that?

Comment: @mkl I am using rotative

Comment: *"I am using rotative"* - I haven't used rotativa at all yet. If I were you, I'd [edit] the question to mention rotativa and add a [tag:rotativa] tag.

Comment: @mkl any other option or library please mention it.

Comment: There are numerous general purpose pdf libraries that feature watermarks. Which is best, depends on details of your use case.

Comment: Consider something like the LEADTOOLS Document Toolkit which allows [adding annotations to a multipage document](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/dotnet-console-add-watermark-to-multipage-file.html). An annotation holding the email ID then can be embedded directly into the output before it is saved. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)